# How did Kiba learn the shadow clone jutsu?

Tags: naruto

The First Hokage sealed the shadow clone jutsu [in the Scroll of Seals](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Scroll_of_Seals). If this is true, how was Kiba able to learn it?

[image: Kiba using shadow clone jutsu]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jutsu sealed in the scroll is the Mass Shadow Clone Jutsu which allows Naruto to create multitudes of clones. The shadow clone jutsu that he is using is the regular version and is commonly known throughout the leaf village.